# Trimming digits at the end of String

Tags: java, regex, string, trim

I want to trim the last occurring numeric characters from  the String
Eg:

- `"abc123"` => `"abc"`
- `"abc12xyz34"` => `"abc12xyz"`

Written  below snippet to extract it. Just want to explore if this can be done by regex

```
private static  String getNumericTrimmedString(String s)
{

    for(int i = s.length()-1; i >=0 ; i--){
        final char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(!(c > 47 && c < 58)){
            return s.substring(0,i+1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Regards,
Brinal

Comment: Yes it is possible, i think saving the string in an array Character by character and cheking is that character is a numeric wiht the next regexp //d that comprobate is that character is a number, then when you have the position do the substring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
private static String getNumericTrimmedString(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\d+$", "");
}
```

`\\d+` looks for one or more digits
`$` is the end of the string

Comment: Cool :) Single liner... Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes that can be done:

```
String s = "abc12xyz34";
System.out.println( s.replaceAll("\\d+$", "" ) );
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `\d+` matches a sequence of at least one digit
- `$` matches the end of the input

Thus, you replace any digits at the end of the string with an empty string, effectively removing them.

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\d*$","");
```